# Lora, carrier frequency and sampling frequency

Tags: digital-communications

I am reading articles on LORA and noticed a problem. For example, if the carrier frequency is $f_0=470$ MHZ, the sampling frequency is defined by $f_s=1$ MHz. For me this is incorrect because normally we must have $f_s \geq 2f_0$.

Why do we make this choice of value for the sampling frequency?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Can you please post a link to the articles you're reading?

Comment: Please _edit your question_ with links to those articles -- I assume you mean [this LoRa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LoRa)?  Subsampling is a valid technique, but we can't really answer _how_ it is in your case without citations of _the specific article you're reading_.

Comment: And note that the Nyquist limit is determined by $f_s \ge 2 B$, where $B$ is the bandwidth.  But it gets a bit complicated.

Comment: This post helps to further explain how "undersampling" works, which is when we can sample a waveform at a higher frequency with a significantly lower sampling clock (as long as $f_s \ge 2B$ for real signals/ sampling): https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/61391/where-should-i-set-my-anti-aliasing-filter-corner-frequency-for-this-signal/61406#61406 .  I am guessing without seeing the articles that this is complex IQ sampling if sampled at only 1 MHz (in order to resolve frequency offsets and support bandwidths that may approach 1 MHz).